# Streaming Music Collection from Apache Server

Tags: linux, networking, apache-http-server, music-management

I've got a raspberry pi as my home server, it's not terribly powerful, but all I use it for is hosting some test projects before they go live. However, I'd really like a way of streaming my vast music collection to my phone and tablet when I'm out and about.

I'm more than willing to look into hacking a system together, but if there's any pre-built solution that would allow me to store my music on a directory on the pi, and access it via a web interface, either on my local network, or from outside, then I'd rather go that route. Preferably something that can run on Apache. Anyone know of such a thing?

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest solution is to store mp3 in your apache www/mp3 directory and then use a web index like this:

http://larsjung.de/h5ai/

The "problem" is that you will need to download the entire mp3 since it has no streaming option out of the box.

If you know a bit of php/html5 maybe you can develop a streaming function

I can suggest you: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

I also suggest you to use Nginx since you have to deal with static content it is lightweight and faster than Apache, expecially on the Raspberry Pi!